# How to prevent Google Cloud Function instance from going down

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a google cloud function in which I initialize some variables on running the function for the first time so that response will be fast from the next time. The variable values lost when I don't use the function for a certain amount of time which means the function is not running when it's not in use.
How can I prevent this?

```
var browser;
var page;

function getBrowserPage() {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        if (!browser) {
            browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: ['--no-sandbox'] });
            console.log('Creating a new browser...');
        }
        if (!page) {
            page = await browser.newPage();
            console.log('Creating a new page...');
        }
        resolve(page);
    });
}

await getBrowserPage().then(p => { 
console.log('page created')
 }).catch(err => {
 console.log(err) 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Trigger a CRON job (via [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/creating)) to invoke your function every few minutes and thus force it to stay warm.

Ideally you'd also like to add handling to your function so that warming/pinging invocations are terminated ASAP; in your case for example we don't want to launch Puppeteer every few minutes for nothing.

[Here's a sample implementation](https://github.com/FidelLimited/serverless-plugin-warmup) in AWS Lambda.

Comment: This is not going to be 100% effective.  Please see the marked duplicate for an explanation why it's not possible to force a function to stay warm.